# What is the correct foreign key constraint syntax for a database migration in Laravel 8.X Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I am a Laravel and Eloquent noob.

I'm trying to do a simple foreign key in a "checklist items" table that takes the primary ID from the "users" table as a foreign key.

Here are my two database migrations:

users:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

items:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateItemsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('itemName');
            $table->string('itemDescription');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        
        Schema::table('items', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
        
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('items');
    }
}
```

attempting to run `php artisan migrate` yields the following error:

```
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.49 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (0.59 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0.33 seconds)
Migrating: 2021_05_04_085648_create_items_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `items` add constraint `items_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

  at D:\Applications\laragon\www\ToDoApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

  1   D:\Applications\laragon\www\ToDoApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")

  2   D:\Applications\laragon\www\ToDoApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

It should be noted that I can achieve what I need fine in the PHPMyAdmin GUI directly, or using basic PHP PDOs, but I don't understand Eloquent and need to understand what I am doing wrong.

I have a feeling that it's to do with a mismatch in the attribute definitions between the two table migrations, but the few things I tried caused alternate errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

columns must be of the same type and sign (signed or unsigned)

`$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();` should be `$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();`

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new Migration file for only the foreign key ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)). something like

*php artisan make:migration add_columns_to_items_table*

Why use different file for same table? Because we make the table first before we make the foreignKey right? :)

Then inside your migration file on up() function:

```
Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
});
```

Yah, its shorter and better for development purpose

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you create the migration for the `many` before the `one` part of `one-to-many` relationship. In your case I guess you created migration for `items` before `users`. Simply rename your migration files according to your relationships. Also please note that your relationship columns must be of the same type. In your case, you are referencing an `integer` of 4-byte to `bigInteger` of 8-byte. (`id` columns is an `unsigned` 8-byte integer).

Answer (score -1):

Replace your `items` migration with the following code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateItemsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('itemName');
            $table->string('itemDescription');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
        
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('items');
    }
}
```